# Remove spaces from a integer - Java

Tags: java, string, input, number-formatting, phone-number

How would I go about changing an integer like '905 123 7023' into something like '9051237023'.

The assignment is supposed to determine if the phone number inputed is a real phone number.

I was going to use this:

```
int phoneNumber;
// Code that turns number with spaces into single number
try {
  System.out.println("Please input an integer");
  input = TextIO.getlnInt();
}

catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
  System.out.println("This is not an phone number");
}
```

To determine the code

Comment: integers don't have spaces

Comment: You cant input integer with spaces.

Comment: `Integer` as stated in earlier comments can't have spaces. For your particular problem you should take the input as `String` and then remove spaces from it.

Comment: Thank you for informing me that you cannot use spaces in code, I feel pretty stupid now :/

Comment: If this is just an exercise, it is OK to assume 10 digit phone numbers only. If it is for real use, you need to be a bit more flexible, and allow for country codes and extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data the user is going to enter will be a string (as it could include spaces, and possibly even letters).

There are several ways to remove spaces from a string:

1. Use split() and join() to split on spaces and join without them
2. use indexOf() to find spaces, remove them using substring, and iterate until no more spaces
3. iterate every character of the string, building a new string out of non-space characters
4. use a regular expression
5. use replace() (thanks @David Wallace - I completely overlooked the obvious one)

Comment: And the simplest of all - `theString.replace(" ","");`  You only need regular expressions to verify that the input matches the right format.

Comment: @David Wallace: You're right - I have edited my answer. The list is hopefully still useful if readers are looking for related solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
//import java.io.*;
//throws IOException 

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int phoneNumber;
try {
    System.out.println("Please input an integer");
    String input = br.readLine();
    phoneNumber=Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll(" ",""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading it in as a `String` if you want to accept phone number input with spaces (or any other hyphens, parenthesis, etc).  Then manipulate the string to turn it into something that could represent an `long`, and parse an `long` out of it.

But given that it's a phone number and you probably won't be doing any math with it, why not just leave it as a `String`?

Comment: You might find that trying to fit a 10-digit number into an `int` will often cause a completely different problem!

Comment: Yea, good point.  But you probably just want to leave it as a `String` either way.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to read the input as a String, verify its in the proper format, and then remove spaces if there are some. Use regular expressions.